# HTMLElement properties return undefined -- Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am writing an Angular component that has a `QueryList` of `HTMLElements` and when iterating over the list, I am able to log each element to console. However when I try to access a property of the element it returns undefined. This is true for every property of the element. I have made sure that the elements are actually present in the list, but they are present as objects with the property 'nativeElement' [Here is the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhIk4.png)

Thank you for considering this.

```
@ViewChildren('element') elements !: QueryList<HTMLElement>

function()
  {
    this.elements.forEach(function(element) {
      console.log(element) //prints object with correct data to console
      console.log(element.className) //prints undefined
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey @Drew have you tried in this way I have shown below as nativeElement object which exposes all the methods and properties of the native elements in angular. Replace `QueryList<HTMLElements>` with `QueryList<ElementRef>` then do as shown below.

```
console.log(element.nativeElement.className);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the typescript in `@viewchildren` to `QueryList<ElementRef>` like this:

```
  @ViewChildren("element") elements!: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Than you can see the autocomplete of the element in the correct way -

```
console.log(element.nativeElement.className);
```

Here is an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mqfa6c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)